# ExtJs 4 ViewPort vs Panel with border layout - Which to use and why?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I have started working on a new application using ExtJs 4. I am new to ExtJs. After reading ExtJs tutorials, it seems to me that Panel and ViewPort is almost same. However only one ViewPort at a moment where as we can have many Panels and nested Panels. I have following scenario :
I have pages as : Page1.html, Page2.html, Page3.html. All have extjs components.
I want to load Page1.html. Page2.html inside a tab in Page1.html. Page3.html inside Page1.html tab.

My question is:
- Why use ViewPort over Panel? Any advantage of ViewPort over Panel?
- How can I load Page2.html inside Page1.html using autoLoad and url? I tried below code but java script inside Page2.html is not executed.

```
{ 
    title : 'Tab3',  
    loader: {
        autoLoad: true,
        url: 'Page2.html',
        renderer: 'html',
        scripts : true, //However script in Page2.html is not executed
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of both [Viewport](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport) and [Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) is rather different. They are not interchangeable in neither direction. What they do have in common is they may contain other components or some web content, because both are [Containers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container).

**Panel is a basic structure to organize your content in a web page.** It can be layed into another container (e.g. panel, window or viewport) and it can organize other components inside. It's very useful and heavily used by both applications and ExtJs framework itself.

**Viewport is the only one - it represents the browser's window** and that's why you can have only one viewport in the page. Other components can be placed inside it, but it cannot be placed anywhere (it's given it's position and size by the browser's window, not anything else).

You seem to fiddle with [ComponentLoader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader), but you haven't clearly explained what is your goal. If you load the content of Page2.html into Viewport of Page1.html, you replace all its content by Page2.html. If you do the same with some panel in Page1.html, only panel's content will be replaced.
And - Page2.html should be designed as "give me the panel's content".

Answer (score 0):

First.. Read the docs and search on the forum like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495293/extjs4-load-panel-from-url)

And about Viewport it's more about the main page view which you arrange your subviews.  panels are for view's area.  All in ExtJS Docs.

Answer (score 0):

They are different...

****ViewPort will fits to the browsers body and organises the child items in a proper manner**** where as Panel need some width and height..so the height&width  of browsers are different so you need to make changes for your every time.Soo

using **viewport is always preferable....**